Grid Search gives nan for best_score with LOGO or LOO, not k-fold CV
I have a nan R2 score problem with grid search.
FDODB=pd.read_excel('Final Training Set for LOGO.xlsx')
array = FDODB.values
X = array[:,2:126]
Y = array[:,1]
Compd = array[:,0]

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

params = {
    'max_depth': [5,7,9],
    'learning_rate': [0.03,0.05,0.07],
    'n_estimators': [200,300,400],
    'min_child_weight': [5,7,9],
    'subsample': [0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
    'base_score': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
}

xgb_reg = XGBRegressor(tree_method='hist', device='cuda')
logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=xgb_reg,
    param_grid=params,
    scoring='r2',
    error_score="raise",
    cv=logo,
    verbose=2,
    n_jobs=-1,
    return_train_score=True
)

grid_search.fit(X, Y, groups=Compd)

best_params = grid_search.best_params_
best_score = grid_search.best_score_

print('Best hyperparameters:', best_params)
print('Best R2 score:', best_score)

Output:
c:\\Anaconda\\envs\\machinelearning\\Lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\model_selection_search.py:1102: UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: \[nan\]
warnings.warn(
Best hyperparameters: {'base_score': 0.5, 'learning_rate': 0.03, 'max_depth': 8, 'min_child_weight': 6, 'n_estimators': 200, 'subsample': 0.3}
Best R2 score: nan

When I used 10-fold CV for grid search, I had any problem to get R2 scores.
But whenever I tried LOO or LOGO CV, all R2 scores are just nan. I checked if my training set had nan values, but it was fine.
What is the possible cause of this and how to resolve it?

Try this:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, LeaveOneGroupOut
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from collections import Counter


FDODB = pd.read_excel('Final Training Set for LOGO.xlsx')
array = FDODB.values

X = array[:, 2:126]  
Y = array[:, 1]     
Compd = array[:, 0]  

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

params = {
    'max_depth': [5, 7, 9],
    'learning_rate': [0.03, 0.05, 0.07],
    'n_estimators': [200, 300, 400],
    'min_child_weight': [5, 7, 9],
    'subsample': [0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
    'base_score': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
}
xgb_reg = XGBRegressor(tree_method='hist', device='cuda')

logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=xgb_reg,
    param_grid=params,
    scoring='r2',
    error_score='raise',
    cv=logo,  
    verbose=2,  
    n_jobs=-1, 
    return_train_score=True 
)

grid_search.fit(X_scaled, Y, groups=Compd)

best_params = grid_search.best_params_
best_score = grid_search.best_score_

print('Best hyperparameters:', best_params)
print('Best R2 score:', best_score)

print('Group distribution:', Counter(Compd))


Thank you for your comment, i still have the same problem, but learnt something new from you
